# How to get Firefox to respect custom print settings when using multiple printers?

Tags: windows, firefox, printing, printer

I have configured custom settings for two printers in Firefox using the print.print settings under about:config.

The issue I've encountered is the settings for the first selected printer persists even when changing the printer to the second printer. I've included steps below to clarify.

Steps

1. Printer1 is specified under print_printer in the about:config settings to be the default
2. User needs to print to Printer2
3. User open the print dialogue
4. Printer1 is selected by default
5. User changes selection to Printer2
6. User hits "Print" to print the page
7. Page comes out using configuration for Printer1 which is incorrect

The inverse occurs if switching the default printer to Printer2 using print_printer, or by clearing the entry which then selects the Windows default printer when printing.

I have also disabled print.save_print_settings to prevent the printer configurations from changing.

I have been testing with a fresh user Profile on Firefox 69.0.1(64-bit) on Windows 10.
For my testing I'm using the orientation settings set below.

print.printer_Printer1.print_orientation = 1(landscape)

print.printer_Printer2.print_orientation = 0(portrait)

The requirement that I need to meet is that users should not need to adjust print settings, just simply select the needed printer.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these settings you could configure directly on the print queue in Windows? If so, that will give you more reliable results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Twisty Impersonator. I made a new Firefox profile to see what happens before settings the custom Firefox settings. It appears attempting to print from Firefox while print.save_print_settings is disabled before settings custom print settings are set seems to use default settings disregarding the Windows settings. If there is a way to send the pages directly to Windows bypassing Firefox, I am unaware of it and would need to be pointed to how to do this.

Comment: It depends on *which* settings you need. What are they?